# CsvFile Header Row does not match output, ex(Header = Tol +, Console output = Tol_plus) C#,csvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, csvhelper

Hello I am parsing a csvFile using csvHelper and Ive come to a roadbloack. One of the headers in the header is "Tol +".I was not able to put it as a variable name, and thus I mapped it as "Tol_plus" using the automapping class. However, when I output the file, I receive:

```
(Console output of Header Row below)
Measurement,Nominal,Tol_plus
```

What I want:

```
(How Header Row  actually looks below)
Measurement,Nominal,Tol +
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class Foo
        {

            public string Measurement { get; set; }//read as string
            public string Nominal { get; set; } //reads in data from here
            public string Tol_plus { get; set; }//reads in data from here 
        }

public sealed class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
        {
            public FooMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.Measurement).Name("Measurement");//maps the variables from the class above to things in quotes
                Map(m => m.Nominal).Name("Nominal");

                Map(m => m.Tol_plus).Name("Tol +");
            }
        }
//main method
void main()
 var textwriter = Console.Out;
             using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(textwriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
             using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"path.csv"))
             using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
             {
                csv.Read();
                csv.ReadHeader();
                csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();//necessary for mapping 
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
              }
//The output here gives me: 
Measurement,Nominal,Tol_plus
```

For this, I tried passing in a string literal to into Tol_plus but that didnt work, would there be a way to map it so it prints out "Tol +" instead of "Tol_plus"?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044320/change-the-name-of-headers-in-csv-file-using-csvhelper-in-c-sharp

Comment: Wow that one line really helped, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Edney's comment:

```
public class Foo
        {

            public string Measurement { get; set; }//read as string
            public string Nominal { get; set; } //reads in data from here

            [CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Name("Tol +")]
            public string Tol_plus { get; set; }//reads in data from here 
        }
```

By adding the line:

```
[CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.Name("Tol +")]
```

It changes the name to "Tol +" during output.